# Why are there 2 durations on the Glimpse SQL tab?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, glimpse

Below I have a capture from the Glimpse sql tab. Note that there are 2 duration columns. One to the right of the record count, and the other is the left most column. The numbers do not match. Why are there two columns? Are they measuring different things?

[image: Screen Capture from Glimpse SQL Tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one on the right most side (i.e. 200.07ms and 211.85ms) are how long the **connection** was opened for. The one next to the record count, is how long the **command** took to execute.