# Entity Framework / Glimpse duration disparity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, glimpse

I'm using the latest ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework (MVC 5.2.2, EF 6.1.2), and latest of Glimpse. I'm working on improving query times to eagerly load an entity with several nested child objects, and have reduced the number of queries by using .Include("Object.Child") to bring in navigation properties. At first, I thought I was getting a good result, seeing the "Total query execution time" in the SQL tab of Glimpse reduce significantly. Yet the "Total connection open time" stays high, and is very long for the resulting combined mega-query. See screenshot below.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand what is going on with the differences in the two durations? Glimpse says my command takes <100 ms, but that the SQL connection takes >5 seconds. The query in this case is really messy with lots of joins etc, however it's not clear where the time goes if indeed the query itself finishes in 100 ms.

Note: I've seen the answer about [why two durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401358/why-are-there-2-durations-on-the-glimpse-sql-tab) here, but it doesn't explain the nature of each.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking the question. The timer for the connection duration starts when the connection is opened and finishes when it is closed. To work this out further, how are you using your context/connection, are you sharing it, keeping it around, etc?

Comment: Thanks Anthony. The context is created when the controller is instantiated, which I believe happens per request, with disposal at the end of the request. I have a complex entity with a hierarchy like A.B.C. When I call context.AObjects.Include("A.B.C"), I'm seeing the resulting query have the long connection duration, but relatively shorter query execution duration.

Comment: I'm wondering now if it is the size of data being returned that accounts for the additional time, if the query is generating lots joined records with duplicate data. Does Glimpse have a way to see the size of the returned result set, vs just the number of records?

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, I think I've figured out what was happening. I saw in another question which suggested that the .Include() approach to eager loading hierarchical entities in Entity Framework can result in complex queries with many joins and duplication of data in the result set. I had a long XML string as one of my properties, so if this was duplicated many times at the database, it would take a long time to return/process.

As a test, I cleared the data-heavy field and reran the query, getting a far shorter "connection" duration (the one list on the right in Glimpse). It went from 9 seconds to under 200 ms total. Based on this I assume the data size was the culprit, and learned my lesson about using large data properties this way.

I'd still be interested to know whether Glimpse could show you the raw data being returned from a query, or even show the size in bytes, along with the record count. This would have likely made this problem evident.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this question, but I encountered the same problem and was also trying to understand the disparity between my query execution time and connection open time.

FWIW, I discovered that I was passing an enumerable in my view model to the view, rather than a concrete list. Thus, the view was triggering evaluation of the query and prolonging the amount of time that the connection remained open. By passing lists of the items (call .ToList() on the enumerable), I *drastically* reduced the amount of time for which the connection remained open.